# i want to share our app in facebook using graph object

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

when i click on share button then it's cout as a i have share actually i din't share our app. how we get our app share actually in wall then give return value share or not. please give me solution

my code

```
enter <script type="text/javascript">
var title = 'LG Pocket Photo Printer';
 var summary = 'Pocket Photo App has various functions to edit your photo. Choose a photo and decorate as you like using various & special effects in Pocket Photo App';
var url = 'http://lgcelebrations.com/lgpocketphoto';
var image = 'http://featherfiles.aviary.com/2013-07-05/m5tanou3rq46rvrd/df05c59155124ef09c1a94c5be7e25ed.jpg';
var fb = window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]='+encodeURIComponent(title)+'&p[url]='+encodeURIComponent(url)+'&p[summary]='+encodeURIComponent(summary)+'&p[images][0]='+encodeURIComponent(image));
fb.focus();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<p><a onclick='postToFeed(); return false;'><img src="images/fb.png" /></a></p>
<p id='msg'></p>

<script> 
  FB.init({appId: "577876348946753", status: true, cookie: true});

  function postToFeed() {

    // calling the API ...
    var obj = {
      method: 'feed',
      redirect_uri:'https://www.facebook.com/cryswashington?fref=ts',
      link:'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
      picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
      name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
      caption: 'Reference Documentation',
      description: 'Using Dialogs to interact with users.'
    };

    function callback(response) {

    document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
    }

    FB.ui(obj, callback);
  }

</script>
```